# Can't install mysql community server 8.0 windows 10. I already have Server 5.7 installed and Workbench 8.0 CE installed

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

I need to run the 5.7 server and the 8.0 server. Not necessarily at the same time, but i need them both installed. I've installed 5.7 and now I can't install 8.0 CE Server.

Downloaded MSI installer from here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html

It offer to update Connector/Python  and that's it.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you mean you can't install? Is there any error and/or message saying that you can't install? If there's any error and/or message, you should include that in your question. That would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: No error message. Just didn't give me the option to install 8.0 server. Or so I thought. Found it. All ok now.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. The installer is just confusing. For other newbies, here's what i learned:

Start the installer and you see:
[Select Products to Upgrade....Connector Python....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJh71.png)

Cancel that, and you see
[List of products already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12pQF.png)

Note that Server 8.0 is not there. Click "Add" on the right. And that's it!